# ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:\Users\aNTA\AndroidStudioProjects\breaking\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, zappdev

Im new to AppDev and learning on my own. While experimenting, i  came across this and finding it hard to resolve at the moment. Can anyone help me out pjease. I am working with Android Studio 3.6

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<activity>xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.breaking">

    <activity>

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</activity
```

The element type "activity" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Josh

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looking messy. If it is really a manifest file code , then it should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.breaking">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="activity name"/>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is the whole manifest file, you have two activity opening and one closing which is at the end.

Error points to the obvious solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<activity>xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.breaking">

    <activity>

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
     **</activity>**
</activity
```

Comment: Thank you all for the assist. Much appreciated.

Comment: can i please add you to talk privately regarding Android Studio projects please?